# Getting webElementId as 'undefined' in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, ui-automation, nightwatch.js

```
module.exports = {

'TESTTT'(browser){
  browser  
    .url ("https://xyz")
    .elements('xpath', '//div[@class="ant-card-head-title"]//span', function (elements) {
        console.log(elements.value)  // It prints all the three web elements
        elements.value.forEach(function (elementsObj) {
            console.log("WebElementID: " + elementsObj.ELEMENT)  // gives undefined
            browser.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT, function (result) {
                
                    console.log('\n' + result.value)
            
            })
        })

    })

  }
}
```

I am using Nightwatch for UI automation. There are three Web elements whose text I want to print. Before the `ForEach` loop when I print (`elements.value`) it gives me all the three elements. But when I print after `ForEach`, it gives '`undefined`' value of a `webElementId`. Why is it giving undefined value?

[image: Error Screenshot]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the .ELEMENT is supposed to be. if you are using vscode and u can't strg+click on ELEMENT then it doesn't exist.

If you want to get the value from the object try my modified code. It works for me ;)

```js
module.exports = {

    'TESTTT'(browser){
      browser  
        .url ("https://xyz")
        .elements('xpath', '//div[@class="ant-card-head-title"]//span', function (elements) {
            console.log(elements.value)  // It prints all the three web elements
            elements.value.forEach(function (elementsObj) {
                // Changed Code below
                let elementID = elementsObj[Object.keys(elementsObj)[0]]
                console.log(`WebElementID: ${elementID}`) // Logs the first property value of the elementsObj
                browser.elementIdText(elementID, function (result) {
                // Changed Code above
                    
                        console.log('\n' + result.value)
                
                })
            })
    
        })
    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Also, could you please tell me what this line means:  let elementID = elementsObj[Object.keys(elementsObj)[0]]

Comment: Thank you, it worked!  Two values of "WebElementID" are printed, but the text value of only one of them is printed. How can I print text values of both web elements?

Comment: the Object.keys(obj) gives you an array with the keys from an object, then if i select the first of this array with `[0]` i get the first key of the object. By then searching for the key with `obj[keyThatIJustFound]` I get access to the first key in an object no matter what the name is to begin with.  It is just a sneaky workaround if you don't know the name of a an objects key xD

Comment: Got it. And how can I print all the text values?